# How to configure CodeceptJs to work with appium for website testing on mobile device

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, codeceptjs

hope you are well, I am trying to configure Codeceptjs to work with Appium, for proof of concept I only need the configuration to naviagte to a website amazon.com for example and create an account.

I have been reading the appium documentation and the following is stated for Chrome on Andriod 'For web tests, to automate Chrome instead of your own application, leave the app capability empty and instead set the browserName capability to Chrome.' Can be found here https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/

So I have left 'app' blank as it tells me to do, but every time i run my test I get the following error

Error: Failed to create session.
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall

My config is as follows, I have been changing settings for the past few days with no luck, any help or pointing me in the right direction would be really appreciated, thank you in advance.

````
```exports.config = {
  tests: './*_test.js',
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
   // WebDriver: {
     // url: 'https',
      //browser: 'chrome'
   // },
    Appium: {
      path: '/wd/hub',
      port: 4723,
      platform: 'Android',
      url: 'https://www.test.com',
      desiredCapabilities:{
        deviceName: "emulator-5554",
        platformVersion: "11.0",
        platformName: 'Android',
        deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
        automationName: 'UIAutomator2',
        browserName: 'Chrome'
      
        
      }
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js'
  },
  bootstrap: null,
  mocha: {},
  name: 'CodeceptJS',
  plugins: {
    wdio: {
      enabled: true,
      services: ['selenium-standalone']
    },
    pauseOnFail: {},
    retryFailedStep: {
      enabled: true
    },
    tryTo: {
      enabled: true
    },
    screenshotOnFail: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Configuration issue on my end, incompatable chrome browser version to to the chrome driver, has been resloved with a simple appium command